# How can I do a linear best fit from one point to another in a matrix multiple times in order to detrend a series?

Tags: matlab, trend

For this type of data I want to do an interpolation like fit from one maxima to a minima and so on, so I can look for superimposed high frequencies:
[image]

I have a matrix of values such as:

```
a=[ 3 7 10 3 1 5 10 5  3 2 4 8 10 7 4 3 4 2 1 4 5 7 10 8 7 6 6 4 3 2];
```

Now I want to choose the relative and maximum and minimum values such that

```
a=[ 3 0 10 0 1 0 10 0  0 2 0 0 10 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 2];
```

I essentially want to fit a straight line from `a(1)` to `a(3)` and then from `a(3)` to `a(5)` and so on, and then subtract the fit from the data.

I know there is a function "detrend" that uses a breakpoint method it denotes as "bp", and that is the closest thing I found resembling my goal.

If you know of a way MATLAB can do this I will greatly appreciate it, otherwise it seems like I have to write an m-file to do it.

Comment: Do you want to do a *piecewise interpolation*? Possibly a *piecewise linear interpolation*?

Comment: Yes that is it. But I am having a hard time actually doing it, or finding a away to do it.

Comment: [`interp1()`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/interp1.html).

Comment: I'm actually not sure precisely what you're trying to do here - *why* do you want to do this?

Comment: I am measuring avariable along time. However fft to analyze the main frequencies does not work as the period of each signal grows with time. I want to detrend the data that looks like a sawtooh function to see if there is any distinguishable periodicity besides the first order fluctuations.

Comment: The problem is points I want to interpolate with are not evenly spaced, and I thought interp1() uses evenly spaced points.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your original question (it was a bit unclear - maybe include a picture next time?) See my answer below; you want to use the empirical mode decomposition.

Comment: Ok cool thank you, I will upload a picture to clear up and left over confusion.

Comment: @Abid: `interp1` also handles deal with unevenly spaced points.

Comment: Your problem statement is much clearer with a picture. :) Definitely consider the EMD for this; it's the kind of problem the EMD was formulated to solve in the first place.

Comment: @Abid: see also my additional notes on why the FFT didn't work and what you should do next time you need to analyse a time-varying function. ;)

Comment: For someone who just found out about EMD, can you tell me if I should detrend first, and then what algorithm have you found that best works? I have found many online and they all seem to have their own unique method or approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what your question is asking for is interpolation between the **local minima** and **local maxima** of a time series (what you call the "relative minimum and maximum values".)

See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169176/how-to-find-tops-and-bottoms-in-time-series) and add some code that does a linear interpolation between the local minima and maxima.

`interp1()` will do this handily. There is no need for the input points or the output points to be evenly spaced.

```
>> x = sort(rand(1,10));
>> y = rand(1,10);
>> plot (x,y,'r.');
>> xx = 0:0.01:1;
>> yy = interp1(x,y,xx);
>> hold on;
>> plot (xx,yy,'b-')
```

[image]

---

What I think you *really* want to do is decompose the signal into components based on local time scale. (that is, where the frequencies change with time). Use the [empirical mode decomposition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10169246/1191425). Wavelet methods might be an alternative, but the output of the EMD is very easy to interpret visually.

[image]

---

Incidentally, the plain FFT won't work if applied to the entire length of a signal that is time varying - the FFT assumes a stationary (non-varying) signal.

You need to apply the Short-Time Fourier Transform, which is the FFT applied over sliding windows of the data to get a picture of frequency over time. See the `spectrogram()` function.

```
>> plot (x,y)
>> x=0:0.001:1;
>> y = chirp(x);
>> plot (x,y);
>> figure;
>> spectrogram(y);
```

[image]

There are issues with time vs. frequency resolution of the short-time Fourier transform that limit its application when your sampling rate is low compared to the frequency of the data. It would would be unlikely to work well for the example data you posted a picture of.

Comment: I found out about the spectogram earlier today and thought it was pretty cool! It is more of a verification tool though I guess to see if your signal is no-periodic, all in all, this answer was super helpful and I look forward to apply it to my school work!