# MatLab, how do I plot multiple waves on top of each other?

Tags: matlab, plot, wave

I have this image taken from user Li-aung Yip, in his response: [Is there a way to do a linear best fit from one point to another in a matrix multiple times in order to detrend a series, MatLab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322606/is-there-a-way-to-do-a-linear-best-fit-from-one-point-to-another-in-a-matrix-mul)

[image]

I would like to know given several time series how MatLab can do this.

Best,
Abid

Comment: Which part specifically are you asking about? How to add the timeseries together to form a new, summed timeseries?  How to create multiple axes in the same figure window?  How to plot multiple timeseries into the same axes object (i.e. the top panel)?  Something else?

Comment: As you can see the various time series red,green, black, and blue. I would like to know how given these,  I can then plot them are represented by figure (a).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the original plots (red,green,black,blue) are of variables `a,b,c,d`, each of which has a point for each `t`:

```
figure;
hold on
plot(t,c,'-k'); %# black line
plot(t,c+b,'-g'); %# green line added to previous
plot(t,c+b+a,'-r'); %# red line added to previous
plot(t,c+b+a+d,'-b'); %# blue line added to previous
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case where `x` is your vector of dates, and `B` is your black line,

```
plot(x,A) % the NR plot
hold on
plot(x,B,'k')
plot(x,C+B,'g')
plot(x,D+B,'r')    
hline(1.2)
hline(1.0)
```